# Fetching Selected Image From An Array to be displayed in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to fetch the selected image from the array of images.And the selected image should be displayed in new view..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

selectedTag = 0;

imagesName = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"nature1.jpg",@"nature2.jpg",@"nature3.jpg",@"nature4.jpg",@"nature5.png",@"nature6.jpg",nil];
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

imageScroll.delegate = self;
imageScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
int scrollWidth = 768;
imageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,605);

int xOffset = 0;

for(index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
{

    UIButton *img = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    img.tag = index;
    selectedTag = img.tag;

    img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    img.frame = CGRectMake(50+xOffset, 120, 270, 350);

    NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];
    imageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,510);
    [imageScroll addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    xOffset += 370;


    [img addTarget:self action:@selector(newView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    selectedTag = img.tag;    
}
}
-(void)newView:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"%@",sender);
int f;
f = [sender tag];


CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250);
[self setView:[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rec] autorelease]];
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imagesName objectAtIndex:f]];


im.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
im.frame = CGRectMake(250, 120, 270, 350);


[[self view] addSubview:im];

}
```

Can anybody help me to fetch the selected image to another view??  Thanks In Advance..

Comment: What's the problem with this code ?

Comment: cant fetch the image which i selected from array..

Comment: Are the images in the app bundle?  Or coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting string instead of image. Use this piece of code

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:f]];
UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```