# Fetching Selected Image From plist to be displayed in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, plist

From my last question i've modified my code to fetch images from plist..My Previous question is in this link([Fetching Selected Image From An Array to be displayed in another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812709/fetching-selected-image-from-an-array-to-be-displayed-in-another-view))

My Code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageList" ofType:@"plist"] ];
self.arrayImages = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Images"];

selectedTag = 0;
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
imageScroll.delegate = self;
imageScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
int scrollWidth = 768;
imageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,605);
int xOffset = 0;
int total = self.arrayImages.count;

for(index=0; index < total; index++)
{
    dict = [self.arrayImages objectAtIndex:index];

    UIButton *img = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    img.tag = index;
    selectedTag = img.tag;
    img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    img.frame = CGRectMake(50+xOffset, 120, 270, 350);
    lab.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 150);
    lab.frame = CGRectMake(160+xOffset, 500, 90, 50);
    lab.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"imagesName"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    lab.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dict objectForKey:@"listName"]];
    [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];
    [lists insertObject:lab atIndex:index];
    imageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,510);
    [imageScroll addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    [imageScroll addSubview:[lists objectAtIndex:index]];
    xOffset += 370;

    [img addTarget:self action:@selector(newView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    selectedTag = img.tag;
}    
}

-(void)newView:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"%@",sender);
int newIndex;
newIndex = [sender tag];
NSLog(@"Selected Tag :%d",newIndex);
CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250);
[self setView:[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rec] autorelease]];
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dict objectForKey:@"imagesName"]objectAtIndex:newIndex]];

UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
UILabel *lab1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lab1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[dict objectForKey:@"listName"] objectAtIndex:newIndex]];


lab1.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 150);
lab1.frame = CGRectMake(360, 600, 90, 50);
lab1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
im.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
im.frame = CGRectMake(200, 120, 370, 450);
[[self view] addSubview:im];
[[self view] addSubview:lab1];
}
```

My Plist Output:

```
   Images =     (
            {
        Contents = "Sea While Tsunami";
        imagesName = "sea1.jpg";
        listName = Sea1;
    },
            {
        Contents = "Sea While Tsunami";
        imagesName = "sea2.jpg";
        listName = Sea2;
    },
            {
        Contents = "Sea While Tsunami";
        imagesName = "sea3.jpg";
        listName = Sea3;
    },
            {
        Contents = "Sea While Tsunami";
        imagesName = "sea4.jpg";
        listName = Sea4;
    },
            {
        contents = "Sea While Tsunami";
        imagesName = "sea5.png";
        listName = Sea5;
    },


 ),
```

I'm Getting error as:

```
<UIButton: 0x714f3a0; frame = (420 120; 270 350); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x4f460>>
2013-02-12 12:58:46.973 image[2546:11303] Selected Tag :1
2013-02-12 12:58:46.975 image[2546:11303] -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x714bd60
2013-02-12 12:58:46.976 image[2546:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x714bd'
***First throw call stack:
(0x8f012 0xcce7e 0x1a4bd 0x7ebbc 0x7e94e 0x3584 0xe0705 0xe97e3 0xe9668 0x1465c 0x26a2 0x25d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

plist works fine..it displays well on first view..but on fetching the selected image to another view i'm getting this error..am i mistaking on initializing fetched image in `newView:`..can anybody help me in solving this problem?? Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it in `YurSecondViewController.h`

```
UIImage *img;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage *img;
```

Make sure you make `property` and `synthesize` **img**.

In the `FirstViewController` where you have that `image`:-

```
YurSecondViewController *View=[[[YurSecondViewController alloc]init];
View.img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:View animated:YES];
```

In your YurSecondViewController.m where you have to show image do:-

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
[imgView setImage:self.img];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: sorry..i cant get u..i cant find this will solve my problem..i'm asking to display selected image which is in plist file..

Comment: yes..images displays from plist..but while passing that selected image it displays error..

Comment: My doubt is on initializing UIImage in -(void)newView:(id)sender{..}  because on that place only this error occurs..

Comment: [[self view] addSubview:im]; ?? r u mentioning this part??

Comment: UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dict objectForKey:@"imagesName"]objectAtIndex:newIndex]];

UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];          [[self view] addSubview:im];
      My doubt on these 3 lines..r these 3 lines r correct??

Comment: my entire code is above..and also i've given my output result too..plz check my question along with code in above??

Comment: send ur code to my mail id - axxxita07@gmail.com and i will give u to bake with solve ur prblem thanks :)

Comment: Thank u patel..but i've found where i've done wrong..my index value in -(void)newView is not updated..